# Combine more html file, 1 of them random taken from a subfolder

Tags: html, batch-file, merge

I need to generate a dynamic signature for my factory's emails.

My need is to make a single signature for each dependent, with his name, then insert down a random jpg (taken from a code in the html file) and then down again a standard signature of my factory with a lot of various link to Facebook, Google+ and so on...

So I tried to make a random function with html file, but when I open my html signature with Thunderbird, I Don't see the random image. Thunderbird generates particular html to include jpg. So I Need to generate them, put them in a folder, and the chose them random.

So my thought was: I take a BATCH script to merge, the first part (`name.html`), the second part (`jpg`, `html` in a subfolder LIKE `1.html`, `2.html`, `3.html` etc.) and the third part (`standardsignature.html`) and generate into another directory X number of signature.html for each user account. Can you help me? Thank you!

I tried that but still not working:

```
@echo off "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\" pause
for %f in (mauro.txt) do type "%f" >> *\DEF\new.txt  
PAUSE
@echo off "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\html"
pause
SET /A html=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
pause
for %f in (%html%.txt) do type "%f" >> DEF\new.txt
pause
for %f in (mauro2.txt) do type "%f" >> *\DEF\new.txt  
pause
```

Comment: You should pay for this ...

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track.  Search SO and you'll find lots of examples that explain how to generate a random number (hint: %random%), and the other parts of your puzzle.  Try writing the batch file yourself, and when you run into a problem, post a new question and you'll get more help.

Comment: sorry but i don't know How to write one.. I think it's not so difficult t write but I don't understand how to use the random function

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File

Comment: @echo off
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd documents and settings
cd Mauro
cd Documenti
cd Firme
cd provamerge
SET /A html=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
pause
for %f in (mauro.txt) do type "%f" >> DEF\new.txt  
PAUSE
CD html
SET /A html=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
for %f in (%html%.txt) do type DEF\new.txt
cd..
for %f in (mauro2.txt) do type "%f" >> DEF\new.txt  
pause

Comment: As you seem to have little knowledge about batch scripting at the moment, do you really need to start with writing scripts of this complexity? Your learning would likely be more efficient if you took smaller steps. Please try either a) simplifying your problem to the point where you feel confident about its implementation and then adding other things to the script one by one as you find out how to do those *or* b) asking simple, specific questions with regard to your present script (but don't forget trying to search for ready answers first).

Answer (score 0):

First off, if you intend to write batch scripts, do some research.  Don't just glance.

```
@echo off "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\" pause
```

All I can do is guess that you are trying to change directory, so here is how you do that

```
cd "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\"
```

And here:

```
for %f in (mauro.txt) do type "%f" >> *\DEF\new.txt
```

This would, for every line in mauro.txt, try to find a file that is named the contents of that line, then read the file.  All you need is this

```
type mauro.txt >> path
```

Also not sure what you are doing with the <kbd>*</kbd> in the redirect path but it's not valid.  Please explain what that was for.

Comment: I used * to include the previuos part of link.. now I make that, but it seems that random fuction doesn't work.. I see always the same photo. Why? @echo off CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\" DEL NEW.HTML type mauro.txt >> NEW.HTML PAUSE SET /A photo=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1 PAUSE ECHO Random: ECHO %photo pause TYPE %photo%.txt >> new.HTML pause type "Firma Inox Pack.html" >> NEW.HTML pause

Comment: Okay how do you seriously expect us to read that unformatted and strung together on one line? I'm not editing your original post again, put forth a little effort if you want people to help you.

Comment: I try but i don't understand how to do that..$@echo off CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\"$DEL NEW.HTML type mauro.txt >> NEW.HTML PAUSE SET /A photo=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1 PAUSE ECHO Random: ECHO %photo pause TYPE %photo%.txt >> new.HTML pause type "Firma Inox Pack.html" >> NEW.HTML pause

Comment: ** @echo off CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\" **

Comment: Then maybe you should try to find out how instead of expecting everything to be done for you, [here, I'll get you started.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: '    @echo off   '
    CD "C:\Documents and Settings\Mauro\Documenti\Firme\ProvaMerge\"    
DEL NEW.HTML
type mauro.txt >> NEW.HTML
PAUSE
SET /A photo=%RANDOM% * 3 / 32768 + 1
PAUSE
ECHO Random:
ECHO %photo
pause
TYPE %photo%.txt >> new.HTML
pause
type "Firma Inox Pack.html" >> NEW.HTML 
pause